# PNRP isn't starting and can't be found

Tags: c#, .net, windows, p2p

I'm trying to get a PNRP based C# application running but I can barely get started with it.

Initially I had to download the .NET framework version 4 to get the correct references available to me.

When the first call is made I get a "pnrp could not be started" exception.

I tried to explore PNRP using netsh, but the command netsh p2p doesnt seem to be available.

Could anyone tell me if there is some add-on I am missing or if I have made a mistake anywhere.

I am running Windows XP Professional, service pack 3.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.

http://msdn.itags.org/visual-studio/70534/